# Composer package - use custom model if exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My apologies if this exists already but my search-fu can not find the answer.

I have a composer package, and want to use my model ONLY IF an existing model doesn't exist *(or extend the custom model)*, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify the "use" command properly inside my composer model. Since I won't know the name of the "app" using the package, I can't extend it.

```
<?php

namespace MyComposer\Package\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyPackageModel extends Model
{
```

If I put it as a config option, I can't use that in the extends i.e `class MyPackageModel extends config('custom_model_name')`

I had thought I should do the check in the ServiceProvider but I can't seem to find the right code to register the proper model name to use in there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to this before, I believe. But my approach was slightly different. See if it makes sense:

1. Create a base class in your own package. This will be the fallback
   model which will be used if the "local" package (the one consuming
   your package) doesn't have it's own version of it;
2. Create a config file which states which model will be used. The default is the model inside your own package (i.e. the fallback);
3. After installing and setting up your package, if a user does nothing they will automatically have your base model available. If they wish to override your base model with a custom local version, they can simply extend your base model and alter the model to be used in their config file.

I've also found that sometimes it's useful for the base model to 1) implement an **interface** that can be checked in your package's logic without relying on a specific class (which, after all, is meant to be overridden, right?); and 2) have most of it's logic inside a **trait** which the "local" model can use without ever having to extend your model (crucial if the local model already extends some other class for whatever reason).

How you approach the code would very much depend what you plan to do with that model. Say, for example, you have a supporting class that creates media entries in your database. Here's your packages model:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Package;

class Media
{
    //...
}
```

And here's the default config:

```
<?php

return [

    'model' => \Namespace\Package\Media::class,
];
```

And here's a sample manipulation, where you actually account for the local app to override your own model:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Package;

class MediaManager
{
    protected function getModel()
    {
        $model = config('package.model');
        return new $model;
    }

    public function createMedia($attributes = [])
    {
        $media = $this->getModel($attributes);
        $media->save();
        return $media;
    }
}
```

That is to say, you never reference any `Media` model literally. You do your manipulations via the `MediaManager`. Of course the logic is very simplistic, but hopefully it's enough to get the bigger picture.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned using a config option above but I don't understand where/how to use it. `class MyPackageModel extends config('custom_model_name')` wouldn't work and I can't sort out how to register that model for use. That was a part that I needed advice on.

Comment: I forgot to mention : thanks for attempting to assist. I also thought about the interface / repository / contract / trait idea but hit the same wall : how do I `use config('custom_model_name')` at the top of a php file or call it in the class if I can't figure out how to pass in the info (in the ServiceProvider)?

Comment: I've added some code samples. Still, keep in mind that what I proposed is not like your original approach. Your package's class should not extend anything form the app implementing it. How could it? The reverse logic makes more sense, I believe.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Tunnel vision had me grasping at crazy straws. Your code samples have slapped my grey matter around enough that I understand what I am really doing again.